# Why does Resources.Load cause a CastException in this case?

Tags: unity

I am doing this:

```
string fontName = "freespin_big";

TextAsset xml = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(fontName);
Texture2D image = Resources.Load<Texture2D>(fontName);

Font font = Resources.Load<Font>(fontName);
if (font == null)
{
    font = new Font();
    AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(font, "Assets/Resources/" + fontName);
}
```

In Resources, we have freespin_big.png and freespin_big.xml. I am planning to import the png and xml and create a font. So I check if the font object is there, if not create it.

But I get this error if the font does not exist yet:

> InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from
>   source type to destination type.

If I try to do this:

```
Font font = Resources.Load<Font>("blorg");
```

Where no files are named "blorg", I get null as I expect.

Shouldn't Resources.Load return null if it finds no *fonts* with the right name?

Answer (score 1):

`Font font = Resources.Load("fontname",typeof(Font)) as Font;`

Using this form, instead of the form with  in it, works.